# Dump Memory for Finding Memory Leak in C++ Application

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

Given an active/live process in linux, how can I dump the memory to analyze the memory leak?

I usually use valgrind but unfortunately, valgrind made the application run extremely slow that it couldn't complete the initialization with other processes on other server.

One of the attempted answers in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/how-can-i-find-a-memory-leak-of-a-running-process) suggested diffing `/proc/[PID]/smaps` to locate the region of memory that is growing.

I tried that and the diff contains:

```
+02511000-2eb548000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                 [heap]
+Size:           12206300 kB
+Rss:            12105644 kB
+Pss:            12105644 kB
```

Then I tried to use gdb to attach to the live process and do:

```
(gdb) dump memory ./dump_outputfile.dump 0x02511000 0x2e2548000
./dump_outputfile.dump: Success.
```

Then, I detached and realized the dump file is empty aka zero byte.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `(gdb) dump memory ./dump_outputfile.dump 0x02511000 0x2e2548000` are you sure about the addresses ? the area you want to dump is about 11Gb !

Comment: Yes, that's why I am trying to dump and figure what's going on.  Since it is 11GB, it must be quite obvious what's going on based on the dump.

Comment: what is append if you dump a smaller memory range ? just to try

Comment: @bruno good call -- if I dump 200MB, it works.  Thanks!  If you could find out the limit, it would be great!

Comment: ok, so I undeleted my answer, to enforce the visibility for other readers, please when you will know the max size put it at a remark of the answer. I don't see a limit in gdb documentation, you will have to do some tries

Comment: @bruno haha, I wish I know.  And I don't think it sounds right to do trial and error.  There should be a document somewhere...let's see if anyone points out.  If not, I will accept your answer tomorrow :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose you checked you have enough disk space for the 11 Go ;-)

Comment: Hmm..good call.  I just checked.  I had a free 15GB partition to dump a ~6GB heap (from 0x0175b000 to 0x191bc8000).

Comment: to analyze 11Gb of memory will not be human, I hope for you it is all the time the same repeated leak ...

Comment: @bruno yeah.  Was hoping for repeated strings and so I could guess which part of the code was called repeatedly.  Turned out the repeated strings in the dumped heap belong to some code I never called (per log file).  Need to come up with other creative ways to diagnose.  Thanks!

Comment: if it is just a problem concerning the free disk space it is a false problem and it is better for you to delete your question

Comment: @bruno nah, I think others might want to know what the limit is for gdb to dump memory.  I don't know how to fully utilize the dump but others might. And they might run into the same question -- why no output

Comment: This is a good example of http://xyproblem.info/. To find your leak, try using https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer

Comment: @EmployedRussian  Thanks for your suggestion.  I will give it a try.  I ended up using pprof + tcmalloc's heap checker to locate my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (gdb) dump memory ./dump_outputfile.dump 0x02511000 0x2e2548000

are you sure about the addresses ?

the area you want to dump is about 11Go !

is that too much for gdb ? try with a smaller size

of course check you have enough free disk space for the result